# Does making a field readonly on pagelayout still show in Edit mode?

Tags: administration, page-layout

I have couple of fields which i am populating through a before trigger. So i dont want these fields to be visible during Edit mode of the object.

I made those fields read only on Pagelayout. But when i go to edit this record i still see these fields and are editable.

There are no recordtypes and there is only one pagelayout for this object.

PageLayout

[image]

Edit mode

[image]

Comment: a common issue if you are the sysad as the profile includes this permission

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It may be due to **Edit Read-Only Fields** permission. If a logged user has this permission on their profile then, he/she can edit read-only fields. Please read out this knowledge article: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000225548&type=1